# Monitor if a process has terminated in C

Tags: process, monitoring, c, fork

### **Introduction**

I am writing a monitoring program in C, which performs the `fork()` and `exec()` cycle. However I need to check whether the child process has terminated or not without blocking the main process, i.e. the monitoring program. Something like this:

*Main process*

```
pid_t child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == 0)
    exec(bar);

while (1) {
    if (the child process has finished)
        foo();
    else
        bar();
}
```

### **What I have tried**

Considering the fact I have the child pid I have tried the following:

- Sending a `kill` call with `signal 0` and examining `errno`:

  `if (kill(child_pid, 0) == -1 || errno == ESRCH)`, which I think is not a good way to track the status of the child process, given that it is not safe from race conditions. Moreover it did not work or at least it seemed so.
- Inspecting with `stat(2)` whether `proc/child_pid` exists. All of the above negative arguments are true in this case as well plus that this method is slower.
- `waitpid(2)`. Unfortunately it blocks the main process.

### **The question**

Is there any other way to obtain this kind of information? Or perhaps I am missing something from the solutions I have already tried?

Comment: `kill`ing a `child_pid` with any signal is perfectly race-condition safe as long as you haven't reaped (=waited on) the child yet, but killing with zero isn't a good way to determine if a process is dead or not. It's perfectly acceptable to kill your zombie child repeatedly, and you won't be getting any ESRCH errors until you `wait`, at which moment the race conditions come.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you pass `WNOHANG` to `waitpid` it should not block.

```
if(waitpid(child_pid, &status, WNOHANG) != 0) {
    // child process has finished
    foo();
} else {
    // child process still running
    bar();
}
```

Comment: what is `status` variable and is initialized with?

Comment: @Babaktrad `status` is an int, and you don't need to initialize it.  It will be set by the `waitpid` function, and you can use other macros to get information from it later

Answer (score 11):

When a process is terminating, you can set up the parent process to get and handle a `SIGCHLD` signal, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html); the signal handler can only call async-signal-safe functions, or set a `volatile sigatomic_t` flag tested outside of the handler (e.g. in your main event loop around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)...), or [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) to some file descriptor (e.g. a pipe or some [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html)). As [Bruce Ediger answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31664444/841108) you can also use the Linux-specific `signalfd`.

Then you can use some waiting function, e.g. [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) (perhaps with `WNOHANG` if you don't want to block) or [wait4(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) to wait the process and get its status, etc.

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for more. It has several chapters on these questions.

Answer (score 7):

If you want your process to not block, or maybe you've got other file descriptors to check up on, you should consider the [signalfd()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) system call if you're writing for Linux.

This system call gives back a special file descriptor that you can use in `select()`, `poll()` and `epoll()` system calls. Set up correctly, a child process exiting causes the kernel to make the special file descriptor readabl. Reading from the special file descriptor gives you a filled-in struct with info about the child process' exit status.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by Basile Starynkevitch covers most common situations.

If you have more unusual situations it can sometimes be useful to make use of a pipe. Before creating the child process create a pipe using the `pipe` system call. After creating the child process close the write end of the pipe in the parent process. Reading from the pipe would block until the child terminates.

This differs from `waitpid` in the following ways:

- Reading from the pipe will wait for the child and all of its children to terminate (unless some of them close the file descriptor before that).
- It is possible to have multiple processes read from the same file descriptor causing all of them to wait for the same process (or processes) to terminate.
- You are not limited to wait for a child to terminate. With this method you can also wait for a parent or a sibling to terminate.
- By using close on exec you can wait for a process to either terminate or successfully perform an `execve` system call.
- You can use the `select` or `poll` system call on the pipe along with other file descriptors.